# Python : Calculate average of all items in a txt.file

Tags: python

I have the following text file and I need to calculate average of sold units.

```
"Time";"unit"
"2022-09-23 12:00:00";8.10
"2022-07-19 14:00:00";8.11
"2022-09-21 14:00:00";7.88
"2022-08-11 07:00:00";7.42
"2022-07-07 00:00:00";7.81
"2022-01-06 01:00:00";8.38
"2022-02-11 02:00:00";9.96
"2022-03-12 07:00:00";10.94
```

**Code to analyze length of file.**

```
file = open ("data.txt",'r', encoding = "utf-8")
row = file.readline()
rows = file.readlines()
length = len(rows)
file.close()
```

Code for total, which I want to divide with lenght.

```
total = 0
file = open ("data.txt",'r', encoding = "utf-8")
row = file.readline()
while (len(row) > 0):
    x = int(row[22])
    total = total + x
    row = file.readline()
    tiedosto.close ()
```

Unfortunately, I got following error message with the current code.

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

I assume that error relates to date as it is inside the strings. What could be the fix for the current code or is there easier way?

Comment: you have to skip the first line, as it does not contain any character at position 22.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `pandas`? If so this is about 2 lines of code.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you prefer single liners you can use this.

```py
with open('data.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    lines = [line.split(';') for line in lines]
    lines = [line[1] for line in lines[1:]]
    lines = [float(line) for line in lines]
    print(sum(lines)/len(lines))
```

Answer (score 3):

Open your file with context manager.

Get a list of all lines in the file. Count the number of lines (excluding the header). Parse all lines except the first and split on semi-colon. That will give you two tokens. Convert the second token to float. Add that value to a running total.

Divide the running total by the counter and print the result.

```
with open('data.txt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    if (count := len(lines) - 1) > 0:
        total = 0.0
        for line in lines[1:]:
            _, v = line.split(';')
            total += float(v)
        print(f'{total/count:.2f}')
```

**Output:**

```
8.58
```

Comment: Great solution. However, why not define `count` as the length of all lines `-1` instead of incrementing it everytime?

Comment: @TheMyth I wrote it in a hurry. Now edited

Comment: Great, also edit the question for the `walrus` operator so that they know.

Comment: @TheMyth The assignment expression (a.k.a walrus operator) is part of the language and has been since 3.8. We're now on 3.11. It needs no further qualification

Comment: Yes I know, but still many people don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

A concise and efficient answer thanks to `rsplit(";", 1)` that splits the lines starting from the right.

`map()` is used to convert the units (as string) to integers.

```py
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()[1:]
units = [x.rsplit(";", 1)[1] for x in lines]
print(sum(map(float, units)) / len(units))
```